# How to handle JSON that filed name without double quote

Tags: php, json

How to parse the JSON that its field name has no double quote in PHP

Here is an example of such a JSON that I received....

```
[{meta_data: [{name: "HANDLE", value: "2"}], compound: { name: "Numeric", entries: [{meta_data: [{name: "partition", value: "2"}, {name: "metric-id", value: "18474"}, {name: "unit-code", value: "2720"}, {name: "unit", value: "bpm"}], simple: {name: "Basic-Nu-Observed-Value", type: "float", value: "72.000000"}}, {compound: { name: "Absolute-Time-Stamp", entries: [{simple: {name: "century", type: "intu8", value: "20"}}, {simple: {name: "year", type: "intu8", value: "12"}}, {simple: {name: "month", type: "intu8", value: "4"}}, {simple: {name: "day", type: "intu8", value: "11"}}, {simple: {name: "hour", type: "intu8", value: "3"}}, {simple: {name: "minute", type: "intu8", value: "10"}}, {simple: {name: "second", type: "intu8", value: "26"}}, {simple: {name: "sec_fractions", type: "intu8", value: "0"}}] }}] }}]
```

Comment: Manually since its not valid JSON without the `"`. If the requirements state that the data is to be exchanged in JSON format then its not really your problem its the app/person supplying the JSON that has the issue. Push back at them and have them fix the issue on their end.

Comment: Then you need to fix the part of the app that generates the JSON, not fix the parsing on the part that consumes it.

Comment: yes, I know. their project is open-source
Btw, would u mind answer it below and let me accept you

Comment: If you can don't do it manually .. you can just try modifying this `pure php` `json` implementation  ... https://github.com/itspriddle/json-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually since its not valid JSON without the ". If the requirements state that the data is to be exchanged in JSON format then its not really your problem its the app/person supplying the JSON that has the issue. Push back at them and have them fix the issue on their end.

Bear Says:

> I am fixing for them :) thx

Ok then you need to fix the part of the app generating the JSON, not necesarily the part consuming it (assuming youre using the standard `json_decode` on the consumption side). If thats the case your inital question really become irrelevant and you may or may not need to post a new question on how best to go about reworking the code to generate proper JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? I tried this on firebug.

```
obj = [{meta_data: [{name: "HANDLE", value: "2"}], compound: { name: "Numeric", entries: [{meta_data: [{name: "partition", value: "2"}, {name: "metric-id", value: "18474"}, {name: "unit-code", value: "2720"}, {name: "unit", value: "bpm"}], simple: {name: "Basic-Nu-Observed-Value", type: "float", value: "72.000000"}}, {compound: { name: "Absolute-Time-Stamp", entries: [{simple: {name: "century", type: "intu8", value: "20"}}, {simple: {name: "year", type: "intu8", value: "12"}}, {simple: {name: "month", type: "intu8", value: "4"}}, {simple: {name: "day", type: "intu8", value: "11"}}, {simple: {name: "hour", type: "intu8", value: "3"}}, {simple: {name: "minute", type: "intu8", value: "10"}}, {simple: {name: "second", type: "intu8", value: "26"}}, {simple: {name: "sec_fractions", type: "intu8", value: "0"}}] }}] }}] 

console.log(obj[0].meta_data);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[Object { name="HANDLE", value="2"}]
```

Comment: He has mentioned the received JSON object, 'Here is an example of such a JSON that I received....'

Comment: PHP is perfectly capable of receiving JSON without involving JavaScript at all.